# Disqus iOs Chrome textarea input

Tags: ios, google-chrome, keyboard, textarea, disqus

We are having trouble with disqus textarea on chrome on iOs.

The problem is that when typing a comment in the textarea, it works fine. But when clicking on the textarea again to move the cursor, and start typing again nothing occurs in the textarea only the backspace works.

Safari on iOs works fine and so does chrome on android.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the trick is to remove focus from the textarea by tapping on plain text elsewhere in the page, then tapping again in the textarea.